# Cordova phonegap image upload

Tags: mysql, cordova, phonegap

I can not upload the image to MySQL  with phonegap cordova and  inappbrowser plugin on Android.

Comment: please visit [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to contribute a good answe

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your code to help you to debug it.

Do you want to save to path to file in database and upload file ?

or save the file in the database (this is not a good idea).

There is a lot of advice to do it, please check this links bellow :

**For upload only, look at this thread:**

[File-Transfer Cordova using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921547/file-transfer-cordova-using-php)

**To upload and save path in database :**

https://codesundar.com/cordova-file-transfer-upload-images

**Other link to read :**

https://github.com/ShashiBadhuk/PhonegapFileUpload

[cordova navigator.camera.getPicture not working in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808733/cordova-navigator-camera-getpicture-not-working-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: Hi thanks  , i want to upload image to mysql and save pic to a folder .I try  with inapbrowser plugin but can not access camera

Comment: <html>
   <head>
      
 </head>
 <body>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>


     <iframe src="baza-f.php" width="97%" height="97%"></iframe>
 </body>
 </html>

Comment: https://github.com/ShashiBadhuk/PhonegapFileUpload  i try to run this  but can not  make apk  cordova build

Comment: edit your post with code and errors logs and use code tags please

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                function onDeviceReady() {
                    window.open('https://mysite/uploud.php', '_self ', 'location=no');
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: i use inapbrowser but in any other way its not posible  what i try

Comment: I find this could solve i will try now  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions

Comment: do not put code in comments please, use your initial post